# Irreduciblity of the polynomial $x^{p^n}-x+1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why $x^{p^n}-x+1$ is irreducible in ${\mathbb{F}_p}$ only when $n=1$ or $n=p=2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122274/why-xpn-x1-is-irreducible-in-mathbbf-p-only-when-n-1-or-n-p-2)

What are the values of $n$ for which the polynomial $$f(x):=x^{p^n}-x+1$$is irreducible over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ ?

I know that for $n=1$ the polynomial is irreducible. Are there any other $n$ for which $f(x)$ is irreducible ?

Comment: This is a [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/122274/11619). Thomas Andrews gives an excellent answer there.

Comment: And see [this related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/93440/11619) for a specific example.

Comment: And [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175131/) with several answers (among which one by OP) that show why the polynomial is irreducible for $n=1$.